difference between local and global dependencies in angular
What is the difference between downloading local and global dependencies? For example, if I run "npm i bootstrap" in the project folder, will I download it from the location?, and if I want to download it, only globally?
search blogs and forums and documentation from angular

Does this answer your question? What is the difference between installing a package locally and globally using npm?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/
Angular has nothing to do with it, your package manager handles them. In this case npm -> node.
